# connect Android 2.3 phone and use PC internet (ubuntu)

Tags: android, usb, root

I managed to conect my phone to the computer and I am able to debug with eclipse but I need internet conection but the phone I got has no sim card and wifi at work doesn't work well (not possible to use wifi) so I woul like to create a bridge like instructed [here](http://blog.mycila.com/2010/06/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-22.html) but it doesn't work.

The problem is I think is that the phone is not rooted. I am not allowed to do any modification to the device like the rooting instructions you can find on the net. Is there something else I can do? just a temporary "su" or sudo on the device? I have the terminal installed on the device and I tried typing su and it says "permission denied". Is there an apk to just activate the su temporary to make the conection and that's it?

The phone is a nexus one with Android 2.3.4.

EDIT: I know I need a linux pc. And at the top of the page it was written that you need a rooted phone but I decided to try it anyway but it doesn't work it seams the phone doesn't "allow it" I also tried what was written on the link [suggested](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkMonitoringBridge?highlight=%28%28NetworkConnectionBridge%29%29)  but it doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need root for reverse usb tethering. You can follow the steps normally without having to type "su" on your device?

If you read the page, you need a linux computer if you want to use reverse tethering AND adb and the same time.

The trick is that you need to execute this I guess:

```
./adb shell netcfg usb0 dhcp
```

to get the usb-connection on your phone.

Comment: I did just that: sudo ./adb shell netcfg usb0 dhcp
and got: action 'dhcp' failed (Permission denied)